# Python and MySQL connector - Connection timed out error

Tags: python, mysql

I have a Python script which connects to my database, gets all the users' hashes and their emails, then parses through those hashes and gets some other data from the DB based on the user's hash value.
The problem is, that my MySQL Python connector breaks at various points and gives me this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 509, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/antonio/Desktop/PythonProjects/crypton-portfolio-api/crypto_tracking_coins/main_with_flask.py", line 701, in get_all_users_with_portfolio_and_accounting_data
    user_coins_from_db = perform_db_query_fetchall('SELECT `portfolio`, `date`, `type`, `invested` FROM `users` WHERE `hash` = %s AND `fake` = "no"', (user_hash, ))
  File "/home/antonio/Desktop/PythonProjects/crypton-portfolio-api/crypto_tracking_coins/helpers.py", line 6, in perform_db_query_fetchall
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 511, in open_connection
    raise errors.InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (timed out)
```

My `helpers.py` file, which includes all the logic for performing SQL queries, looks like this:

```
import mysql.connector
from config import *

def perform_db_query_fetchall(query: str, params: tuple):
    # Initiate DB connection
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=DatabaseConfig.host_db,
        user=DatabaseConfig.user_db,
        password=DatabaseConfig.password_db,
        database=DatabaseConfig.database_db
    )
    # Initiate DB cursor
    c = mydb.cursor()
    # Execute SQL query and get the results
    c.execute(query, params)
    results = c.fetchall()
    # Close the DB connection
    c.close()
    mydb.close()
    # Return the results
    return results

def perform_db_query_fetchone(query: str, params: tuple):
    # Initiate DB connection
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=DatabaseConfig.host_db,
        user=DatabaseConfig.user_db,
        password=DatabaseConfig.password_db,
        database=DatabaseConfig.database_db
    )
    # Initiate DB cursor
    c = mydb.cursor()
    # Execute SQL query and get the results
    c.execute(query, params)
    results = c.fetchone()
    # Close the DB connection
    c.close()
    mydb.close()
    # Return the results
    return results

def perform_db_query_with_commit(query: str, params: tuple):
    # Initiate DB connection
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=DatabaseConfig.host_db,
        user=DatabaseConfig.user_db,
        password=DatabaseConfig.password_db,
        database=DatabaseConfig.database_db,
        autocommit=True
    )
    # Initiate DB cursor
    c = mydb.cursor()
    # Execute SQL query and get the results
    c.execute(query, params)
    # Close the DB connection
    c.close()
    mydb.close()
    return
```

I'm looping with a `for` loop (about 1900 iterations of the loop) and doing approximately as twice as many SQL queries in that `for` loop.

It always ends not finishing the job that I need the script to do with just printing out the above mentioned `Connection Timed Out` exception.

Interesting fact is, that it always crashes on different stage. The last I tried, it failed on the 1600th~ iteration. Sometimes it fails on the 30th~ iteration...

Any ideas what can I do to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the database server is running out of free space. In my case the database server was full.

Comment: This is not the case. We have plenty of RAM and HDD space left on all partitions. Any other ideas?